# How to move the pointer by arbitrary amount in BrainFuck?

Tags: brainfuck

For example, if the array is like `0 0 0 0 ... 0 0[n]s o m e d a t a 4 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 3 7 ...`, how to move the pointer by n, without changing `s o m e d a t a 4 9 9 9 ...` after the pointer is moved?

Comment: @Clement Herreman : Actually, I'm *trying to implement* [quicksort in BF](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/implement-quicksort-in-brainf), however, it is unlikely to succeed because I'm not familiar with BF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice challenge. I love this language :)

My solution is (I think) somewhat correct, it moves the cursor after the data of length n without changing it, **but** it moves the data two cells to the left (or one, provided certain conditions are met). Here is the code, hope you find it useful.

The requirements are:

- there is an empty cell to the left of the data **and**
- the pointer is pointing to that empty cell **and**
- there are no empty cells in the data itself.

Here is the code:

```
>[<->+]<[>>[-<+>]<<[->>+<<]>[-<+>]>[-<+>]<-]
```

**Example**: an array `7 9 6`, so `3` tells how far to move the cursor.

```
0 3 7 9 6 ?   this line represents data; values are numbers in cells
^             this shows the pointer location

>[<->+]< gives

3 0 7 9 6 ?
^

now the loop; while the pointer is not zero
[

>>[-<+>] gives in first iteration
3 7 0 9 6 ?
    ^

<<[->>+<<] gives in first iteration
0 7 3 9 6 ?
^

>[-<+>] gives in first iteration
7 0 3 9 6 ?
  ^

>[-<+>] gives in first iteration
7 3 0 9 6 ?
    ^

<- decreases the loop pointer and gives in first iteration
7 2 0 9 6 ?
  ^

which means the loop can continue giving
7 2 9 0 6 ?
7 0 9 2 6 ?
7 9 0 2 6 ?
7 9 2 0 6 ?
7 9 1 0 6 ? after the second iteration and finally
    ^
7 9 6 0 0 ? after the last
      ^
] which is where the loop will end
```

Now, *if* there is an additional empty cell to the left of the whole sequence, then we can move the data one cell to the right.

```
0 7 9 6 0 0 ?
        ^

<[[>+<-]<] gives
0 0 7 9 6 0 ?
^

>>[>] gives finally
0 0 7 9 6 0 ?
          ^
```

So the cursor is moved behind the data of an arbitrary length, however shifting the data one cell to the left.

*Disclaimer* There might be errors in the code, but the idea itself should be clear. Feel free to correct the code whenever it does not match the example.

Comment: Thank you! However... it turns out that I can't even do the sorting of an array of length 4... :P.. Anyway, thanks for the description!

Comment: I know you needed it for sorting, but the question was about moving the pointer :P I may toy around with quicksort at some other time... ;)

Comment: I think you need to transpose the `+` and `-` in your first block. Also, are you missing one `>[-<+>]`?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I think you are correct, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too obvious, but you can slide the pointer to the next zero, with `[>]` or `[<]`. So can you add 1 to your data cells (packing a peano) and subtract 1 before output (`[-.>]`)?

Sadly, this may not offer fine enough control.